# Accessing complex object in multiple threads w/ PHP pthreads

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I have an application made of a Scanner, Parser and Queue class. I'm trying to make use of multithreading in the `run()` method of the Parser class using [PHP pthreads](http://pthreads.org/).

```
class Scanner {
    public function performScan() {
        // Add initial task
        $initialTask = "Task 1";
        TaskQueue::addTask($initialTask);

        $i = 0;
        while(true) {
            // Get task from queue
           $task = TaskQueue::getTask();
           if ($task == null)
               break;

            // Handle task
            $parser[$i] = new Parser($task);
            $parser[$i]->start();

            // Join
            $parser[$i]->join();
            $i++;
        }

        // Done
        echo "Done\n";
    }
}

class Parser extends Thread {
    private $task;

    public function __construct($task) {
        $this->task = $task;
    }

    public function run() {
        // Perform a time-consuming operation
        // This operation adds an unknown number of extra tasks
        sleep(1);

        // Add new tasks to queue
        foreach(range(0, 4) as $i) {
            TaskQueue::addTask("Task {$i}");
        }
    }
}

class TaskQueue {
    private static $queue = array();

    public static function addTask($task) {
        self::$queue[] = $task;
        echo "Add task to queue!\n";
    }

    public static function getTask() {
        if (sizeof(self::$queue) > 0) {
            $task = array_shift(self::$queue);
            echo "Get task from queue!\n";
            return $task;
        }
    }
}

$scanner = new Scanner();
$scanner->performScan();
```

The expected scenario is that the scanner keeps running until it is out of tasks (in this case, indefinitely):

```
Add task to queue!
Get task from queue!
Add task to queue!
Add task to queue!
Add task to queue!
Add task to queue!
Add task to queue!
Get task from queue!
Add task to queue!
Add task to queue!
Add task to queue!
Add task to queue!
Add task to queue!
Get task from queue!
^C
```

Instead, the scanner stops after executing the first thread because there are no more tasks in the queue:

```
Add task to queue!
Get task from queue!
Add task to queue!
Add task to queue!
Add task to queue!
Add task to queue!
Add task to queue!
Done
```

I assume this happens because the thread creates a local copy of the TaskQueue (as it is not a simple object, like an integer or a string) and adds tasks to that copy instead of the copy used by the Scanner class. I've read through the [examples on Github](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/tree/master/examples), but I'm unable to come up with a proper solution.

**Update:** I modified the code to use `wait()` and `notify()` as suggested, but I'm still seeing the same results.

```
class Scanner {
    public function performScan() {
        // Add initial task
        $initialTask = "Task 1";
        TaskQueue::addTask($initialTask);

        $i = 0;
        while(true) {
            // Get task from queue
           $task = TaskQueue::getTask();
           if ($task == null)
               break;

            // Handle task
            $parser[$i] = new Parser($task);
            $parser[$i]->start();

            // Wait
            $thread = $parser[$i];
            $thread->synchronized(function() use($thread) {
                while (!$thread->awake) {
                    $thread->wait();
                }
            });

            // Join
            $i++;
        }

        // Done
        echo "Done\n";
    }
}

class Parser extends Thread {
    private $task;

    public function __construct($task) {
        $this->task = $task;
    }

    public function run() {
        // Perform a time-consuming operation
        // This operation adds an unknown number of extra tasks
        sleep(1);

        // Add new tasks to queue
        foreach(range(0, 4) as $i) {
            TaskQueue::addTask("Task {$i}");
        }

        // Notify
        $this->synchronized(function(){
            $this->awake = true;
            $this->notify();
        });
    }
}

class TaskQueue {
    private static $queue = array();

    public static function addTask($task) {
        self::$queue[] = $task;
        echo "Add task to queue!\n";
    }

    public static function getTask() {
        if (sizeof(self::$queue) > 0) {
            $task = array_shift(self::$queue);
            echo "Get task from queue!\n";
            return $task;
        }
    }
}

$scanner = new Scanner();
$scanner->performScan();
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JoeWatkins I'm sorry, updated the example code to actually work now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Cond::wait()` in `getTask()` to make the Scanner to wait until there are more tasks, and `Cond::signal()` in `addTask()` when you insert a new task, to awake him up and keep picking tasks

http://php.net/manual/en/cond.wait.php

http://php.net/manual/en/cond.signal.php

Another approach is to use the `wait()` and `notify()` methods from `Threaded` class

Comment: I was under the impression that wait() and notify() weren't required when `$thread->join()` was called (as that makes sure the calling thread waites until the second thread has completed)?

Comment: @PeterVanAkelyen `join()` is used to make sure that a threads ends/wait for another thread to finish at the same time (is used like a barrier). wait is used to stop a thread until we know we can wake him up

Comment: I updated the code to use `wait()` and `notify()` but I'm still seeing the same results.

Comment: @PeterVanAkelyen `wait()` /  `notify()` works on what is called object monitors. They must be held by the same object, thats why, `notify()` should be inside `TaskQueue.addTask()` and `wait()` should be inside `TaskQueue.getTask()` . The `TaskQueue` object will become the monitor.